# neovim move config over ssh using VIMINIT (almost working)

Tags: vim, ssh, fish, neovim

So i'm trying to move my neovim config over ssh automatically I do this using the following trick in my ssh config:

```
Host *
    SendEnv LC_VIMINIT
    RequestTTY yes
    RemoteCommand export VIMINIT=$LC_VIMINIT
```

What I'm doing here is sending the content of the environment variable LC_VIMINIT over ssh and once it's content is moved into the VIMINIT environment variable.

In order to fill the content of LC_VIMINIT I have the following in my fish.config (fish shell)

```
set -gx LC_VIMINIT (cat ~/.config/nvim/init.vim)
```

When I connect through ssh and do `echo $VIMINIT` it works and contains my vim config! When starting neovim however my config is not loaded :(

If I do `export VIMINIT='set number'` and start neovim it shows line numbers and VIMINIT is properly loaded.

I'm not sure why it's not working, my current hypothesis is that `(cat ~/.config/nvim/init.vim)` removes the line breaks which causes neovim to ignore it's content?

Maybe someone more experienced can enlighten me?

Comment: Perhaps use the `env` command to inspect the environment to see whether your `LC_VIMINIT` looks correct? Do you have any special settings in your vimrc that might not be easy to translate to a VIMINIT? Perhaps try with a smaller vimrc until it works, then add settings back until it breaks?

Comment: hmm... that `env` command is handy ^^ 

It turns out that the command `set -gx LC_VIMINIT (cat ~/.config/nvim/init.vim)` removes the line breaks, already on my local machine.

Comment: Try: `set -gx LC_VIMINIT (cat ~/.config/nvim/init.vim | string split0)`... Or try bash or zsh ... (Wasn't fish shell supposed to make your life easier? Seems to me it's mostly creating new problems...)

Comment: @filbranden Turns out cat splits each new line into an argument array the exact same thing would happen in bash. It works with `(cat ~/.config/nvim/init.vim | string collect)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following in your `.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
    SendEnv LC_VIMINIT
    RequestTTY yes
    RemoteCommand export VIMINIT=$LC_VIMINIT
```

Next put the following in `./config/fish/config.fish`:

```
set -gx LC_VIMINIT (cat ~/.config/nvim/init.vim | grep -P -o '^.*(?=")|^[^"]+$' | awk '{if($1~/autocmd/){ print "execute \""$0"\""} else {print $0}}' | string collect)
```

What is happening here is that:

1. The content of `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` is stripped from it's comments by grep.
2. Then each line starting with `autcmd` is wrapped in `execute "<line>"`
3. This is collected into a single string
4. The string is placed into the `LC_VIMINIT` environment variable (any LC_* environment variable can be send over ssh).
5. `LC_VIMINIT` is send over ssh when connecting to a host because of the setting `SendEnv LC_VIMINIT`.
6. Upon connecting to the host the variable `VIMINIT` is filled with the content of `LC_VIMINIT` because of `RemoteCommand export VIMINIT=$LC_VIMINIT`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to be able to do what you want.  What my copy of Vim says is this:

> The value of $VIMINIT is used as an Ex command line.

Notice the article "an".  As I read it, you may pass a *single* command line, not multiple Ex command lines separated by newlines.

You could, of course, try to concatenate them with `|`, but that won't work for certain Ex commands.

I also don't think you can get a shell and executed a `RemoteCommand` at the same time, and even if you could, the `RemoteCommand` would probably be executed in a separate, non-interactive shell.

Most people just create a Git repository and sync their dotfiles that way, which is both easier and more elegant.  Of course, that's inconvenient if you're working with many machines, but since I have a custom color scheme and a variety of additional plugins, I just deal with using the defaults in that case.

Comment: I just tested `VIMINIT=$'set nu\nset rnu' vim` and it worked as expected, enabling both `'number'` and `'relativenumber'`, so I don't think this is actually the problem...